# ShinobiCharts axisRange always 0-1

Tags: ios, shinobi

I'm trying to access the real number range of an `SChartAxis` object, with the following:
`chart.yAxis.axisRange`, but this always returns a range of 0-1 regardless of what the real units are. The same method for the x axis, `chart.xAxis.axisRange`, however, returns the actual real number range for that axis (i.e. in the range of the chart units). Is this normal behavior and if so, how can I get the actual real range of the y axis on a `ShinobiChart` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking the axis for its range before it has first rendered. [0,1] is the default range for an axis, and it will be updated once the data has been processed.

Therefore, if you ask the axis for its range during the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller which is creating the chart then it will not report the correct axis range (since it has not yet been calculated).

The delegate method `sChartDidFinishLoadingData:` marks the point when the data has been loaded, and hence the correct ranges have been set on the axes. e.g.:

```
- (void)sChartDidFinishLoadingData:(ShinobiChart *)chart
{
    NSLog(@"%@", chart.yAxis.axisRange);
    NSLog(@"%@", chart.xAxis.axisRange);
}
```

Hope that helps.